# Taking output from command and inserting into .csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I need help with this.

This command typically returns 2 to 3 lines of output. See 2 examples below

```
 # nc -z -w 5 -v server123.liar.com 1002
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

or

```
# nc -z -w 5 -v server456.liar.com 1002
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.10.1.199:1002.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.02 seconds.
```

I need for each line of output to be a row a csv file. I wrote this but for some reason it's not inserting the output into the file as desired. Also may need someone to confirm if this is the right way to write to .csv

```
 #!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%F.%H%M)
FILENAME=nc_results-${DATE}
touch $FILENAME

for SERVER in $(cat my_server_list)
do
        CONNECTSTAT=$(nc -z -w 5 -v $SERVER 1002 | grep "Connect" | grep -v "Version" 2>&1 )
        echo $SERVER "," $CONNECTSTAT  >> $FILENAME
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove unneeded vars and processes, and never use `for x in $(cat ...)`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read server             # this loop reads from your list file
do while read line            # this loop reads from each ncat execution
   do case "$line" in         # case replaces both grep calls
      *Version*) continue ;;  # skips Version, even if line also has Connect
      *Connect*) printf "%s,%s\n" "$server" "$line" ;; # prints formatted
      esac
   done < <( nc -z -w 5 -v $server 1002 2>&1 ) # feeds the inner loop
done < my_server_list >> nc_results-$(date +%F.%H%M) # feeds outer, saves output
```

`read` is probably slower than `grep`'s, but I prefer the `case` for this.
If you do not -

```
#!/bin/bash
while read server             # this loop reads from your list file
do nc -z -w 5 -v $server 1002 2>&1 | # you were only catching grep's errors
     sed -n "/Version/d; /Connect/{ s/^/$server,/; p; }" # 1 sed vs 2 grep 
done < my_server_list >> nc_results-$(date +%F.%H%M) # feeds outer, saves output
```

This is probably better.

Comment: THanks for the response. But i tried this just noe and seems like we're missing a "}" somewhere because im getting an error form your 2ND suggestion

sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'